# Dashes stroke-dasharray in Android Vector

Tags: android, vector, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

How to add dashed line on Android Vector Drawable? It seems "stroke-dasharray" from svg is not supported in Android Vector.
Is any other way to do it?
My drawable that I want to make dashed:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="61dp"
    android:height="160dp"
    android:viewportWidth="61.0"
    android:viewportHeight="160.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M2,159C6,81.5 38,21 57,4"
    android:strokeColor="#FFCF4D"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android.stroke-dasharray="1"
    android:strokeWidth="3"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M49,2L59,2L59,12"
    android:strokeColor="#FFCF4D"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeWidth="3"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried with android:android.stroke-dasharray ?

Comment: @RonakJoshi yes, but it not work

Answer (score 19):

From the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

> Strokes and fills Supported:
>
> Strokes, including color, opacity, width, join, cap, dashes, and
>   alignment. Solid color fills and strokes. Stroke and fill colors
>   specified as RGB, Lab, or CMYK.
>
> **Conversion details:**
>
> **If a stroke is dashed, clipped using a clipping base, or uses an alignment different from center, Vector Asset Studio
>   converts it into a fill shape in the vector drawable.**

So in short, Android Vector Drawables don't support dashed strokes yet.

You can import SVG files that contain dashed strokes but Vector Asset Studio will convert them to fill shapes.

Comment: Confirm. I use a SVG with `stroke-dasharray` and it also transform to fill shape circle.